# converting Prefix to Infix with including parenthesis

Tags: c++, prefix, parentheses, infix-notation

I'm trying to implement a recursive program to convert prefix to infix(prefix include parenthesis) in c++,i dont Know what to do with parenthesis.
i will appreciate give a hint as what to do with parenthesis?
that's what i have got so far.The input should be for example something like this:

```
(= 0 (+ (* 2 (* var_1 var_1)) (* (-4) var_1) 2))
```

and the output must be this:

```
(0=(2*(var_1*var_1))-(4*(var_1))+2)
```

Instead, my program prints me this:

```
(0=((2*(var_1*var_1))+(4*(var_1-2))))
```

That's the code I wrote so far:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> VecSplited_str;
    string InputPrefx_str= ReadInputFile();
    VecSplited_str=split((char*)InputPrefx_str.c_str());
    InputPrefx_str.clear();
    EvalPrefix_exp(VecSplited_str);
}
```

void Convert_PrefixToInfix(stack* Stk_Pointer )
{

```
try
{
    if ( !Stk_Pointer->empty() )
    {
        std::string token = Stk_Pointer->top();
        Stk_Pointer->pop();
        replace(token.begin(), token.end(), ')', ' ');
        replace(token.begin(), token.end(), '(', ' ');
        token=trim(token);
        if (isOperator(token))
        {
            std::cout << "(";
            CalcInfixExp_str+="(";
            Convert_PrefixToInfix( Stk_Pointer );
            std::cout << token;
            CalcInfixExp_str+=token;
            Convert_PrefixToInfix( Stk_Pointer );
            std::cout << ")";
            CalcInfixExp_str+=")";
        }
        else if(isspace(token))
        {
            Convert_PrefixToInfix( Stk_Pointer );
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << token;
            CalcInfixExp_str+=token;
            if ( !Stk_Pointer->empty() )
            {
                if(!isspace(Stk_Pointer->top()))
                    Convert_PrefixToInfix( Stk_Pointer );
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(exception ex)
{}
```

}